# Can I disable the flashing white secret indicator?

Tags: metroid-dread

In *Metroid: Dread*, sections on the minimap will flash white if they contain undiscovered secrets. I'd like to try finding these secrets without the game pointing out their location.

Is there any way to disable these flashing white minimap hints?

[image: minimap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't disable the flashing. The only way to get rid of flashing is to obtain the secret relevant for each section of flashing. This also includes areas where you do not yet have the relevant upgrade to obtain said secret.